# Querying a many to many table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to query a table and I'm having a hard time figuring out the query.

This are my tables(simplified):

```
Member
ID  | NAME
1   | Frans
2   | Eric
3   | Stephan
4   | Kris

Evenement
ID  | NAME
1   | Picknic
2   | Party
3   | Movie

Evenement
ID_EVENEMENT    | ID_MEMBER 
1               | Kris
1               | Stephan
1               | Eric
2               | Eric
2               | Frans
3               | Frans
3               | Stephan
```

Alright, the query I want to do is this:

I want to

```
select
    member_evenement.ID_MEMBER and member_evenement.ID_EVENEMENT
from
    member_evenement
where
    member.ID on member_evenement.ID_MEMBER
where
    member_evenement.ID_MEMBER does not exist
        for each member_evenement.ID_EVENEMENT
```

separately.

I'm using sql server 2008 R2

I hope I explained my question well enough.

If these are my base tables

```
Member
ID  | NAME
1   | Frans
2   | Eric
3   | Stephan
4   | Kris

Evenement
ID  | NAME
1   | Picknic
2   | Party
3   | Movie

Member_Evenement
ID_EVENEMENT    | ID_MEMBER 
1               | Kris
1               | Stephan
1               | Eric
2               | Eric
2               | Frans
3               | Frans
3               | Stephan
```

then the result of my query should look like this:

```
Evenement
ID_EVENEMENT    | ID_MEMBER | MEMBER_NAME   | EVENEMENT_NAME
1               | 1         | Frans         | Picknic
2               | 3         | Stephan       | Party
2               | 4         | Kris          | Party
3               | 2         | Eric          | Movie
3               | 4         | Kris          | Movie
```

Comment: Can you post some SQL you've tried?  THis may help you get started with the joins: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html  and I'm having trouble understanding what you want... YOu want all records from member where they don't exist in Member_evenement? IF so you just need a left join from member to member_evenement where the ID_Member in Member_evenement is null.

Comment: evenement table has a field called ID_Member with STRING data as opposed to 1, 2,3   which is the ID of member?  Ok I think what you're after is all of the members who were not part of an event.  So Frans wasn't in member_evenement 1 so Frans shows up.  But the data in Member_Evenement.ID_Member is wrong (I hope)

Comment: Yeah fixed that, just refresh :p

Comment: If for an evenement there are NO members; do you want all Members to show up for that evenement?  jso if 4: Dance and no records in Membmer_Evenement you want to see all 4 members?

Comment: Yes, In that case I want to see all members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT e.ID AS ID_EVENEMENT, m.ID AS ID_MEMBER, 
  FROM Evenement e, Member m
EXCEPT
SELECT ID_EVENEMENT, ID_MEMBER 
  FROM member_evenement;
```

Comment: I see! EXCEPT is analogous to the MINUS/difference operator in the relational model! And if I want to show the names of the members and events, all I have to do is pass the result to a from statement and do a join on that!

Answer (score 1):

To return all combinations of member and evenement that are not recorded on the member_evenement table, try the following:

```
select e.id id_evenement,
       m.id id_member,
       m.name member_name,
       e.name evenement_name
from member m
cross join evenement e
left join member_evenement me
on e.id = me.id_evenement and m.id = me.id_member
where me.id_evenement is null or me.id_member is null
```

(This assumes that id_member is actually the member's id, and not their name as in the sample data.)

Comment: I'll let mark take it from here. no point in me trying to teach you to fish if someone is fishing for you.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility, which gives the exact same execution plan as Mark Bannister's and onedaywhen's answer is the following:

```
SELECT member.id AS memberid, evenement.id AS evenementid 
FROM member 
CROSS JOIN evenement WHERE
  NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT NULL AS [Empty] 
    FROM member_evenement 
    WHERE member_evenement.memberid = member.id 
    AND member_evenement.evenementid = evenement.id
  )
```